# $\sin{(f(x)-f^3(x))} = x^{100}$ with $f(0) = 0$, how to find $f^{(300)}(0)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Given that $\sin{(f(x)-f(x)^3)} = x^{100}$ where $f:[-1,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(0)=0$ what is $f^{(300)}(0)$?

I tried just to take the derivate of the equation, but it doesn't work. Is there any "special" way to solve it?

Comment: Also, which $x$'s should we use? What are the domains?

Comment: Cause clearly $|x|\leq 1$ otherwise theres a problem with sine

Comment: That doesn't make much sense.  If x = 2 then sin (f (x)-f^3 (x)) > 1 which is impossible.

Comment: Maybe you could try using the sum rule for sine and then use the condition $f(0)=0$.

Comment: It makes sense on $[-1,1]$. The Taylor expansion of $f$ should be on the form $f(x) = a + b x^{100} + c x^{200} + d x^{300} + \ldots$. Try this ansatz in conjunction with the Taylor expanion of $\sin(x)$ to $O(x^3)$. Should give something like $-300! \frac{7}{12}$

Comment: I think the answer is $\pi n$. Try using the formula for the sine, you'll get $f^3(0)=\pi n $. Then differentiate the sine formula and plug in zero, for each differentiation you'll show that all the derivatives (in pairs of two) are equals, hence also $f^{300}(0)=\pi n$. I guess you could also use induction

Comment: What does "upd. sry" mean? Are you in such a hurry that you do not have time to spell out words?!

Comment: A small correction to the comment above: I missed the condition on $f(0)$. If $f(0) = 0$ then I find that $f$ has the Taylor expansion $f(x) = x^{100} + \frac{7x^{300}}{6} + \frac{143}{40}x^{500} + \ldots$ giving $f^{(300)}(0) = \frac{7}{6}\cdot 300!$.

Comment: @Winther That's better. I also get the same from $\arcsin t=t+\frac{t^3}{6}+O(t^5)$.

Comment: @A.G. Good. Doing the $\arcsin$ expansion is likely much easier than expanding $\sin(\cdot)$ as this leads to a much simpler equation-set to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the formula $$\sin(a-b) = \sin(a)\cos(b)-\cos(a)\sin(b)$$ to expand the first expression. Plug in zero and you get that $f^3(0)=\pi n$.

Then differentiate both sides wrt $x$ the sine expression and plug in zero, using what you found above you'll see $f'(0)=f^4(0)$ . Continuing this process of differentiation and plug in zero you'll show all the derivatives are equal at zero, so the result is $\pi n$.

For example, for the second derivative you'll show $f^2(0)=f^5(0)$ and so on!

Comment: Ffs these notation conventions

Comment: What is $n$ here?